# How to use Groovy to load npm package in Jmeter? How to load external js lib in Jmeter?

Tags: javascript, groovy, jmeter

Recently I started learning Jmeter and I see a lot of answers suggesting to use groovy over JS. However, I am unsure as to how can I write my JS code in Groovy. Also, how to use packages like 'jsencrypt' and 'moment' in JMeter preprocessors JSR to do some scripting before calling the sampler.

1. Can I achieve the task that I do in JS in Groovy? How?
2. Right now I write this code in my JSR223 prepoccessors it throws error:

   ```
   var JSEncrypt = require("jsencrypt");
   var moment = require('moment');
   let encrypt = new JSEncrypt.JSEncrypt({default_key_size: 512});
   // code continues
   ```

How can I use this external lib inside my preprocessor?

Answer (score 0):

1. If it's really your code you should be able to write it in Groovy. You can take a look at [RSA Example](https://smartcodeschool.blogspot.com/2014/10/rsa-example.html) to learn how to do RSA encryption/decryption
2. It is not possible to use JSEncrypt library because it [relies on navigator](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/blob/master/bin/jsencrypt.js#L2624) object and [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) means "browser" and you don't have any browser in JMeter

The only way you can re-use your current code in JMeter is via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)

Comment: Hey @Dmitri , I was actually able to use the jsencrypt library successfully. I ll post the code above.However, on more thinking, I wonder if its really necessary to use JS lib for achieving encryption when the same can be achieved via java At the end the value should be encrypted via RSA when send to server. In case of java the encryption library may be readily available since Jmeter is built on it. What do you think?